# Link to specific sheet in embedded Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, embedded-documents

Due to the great number of sheets I will have in my Google Sheets I want to create links to all sheets on the first sheet. This works within Google Sheets with the following code:

```
function goToSheet2() {
     goToSheet("Sheet2");
}
function goToSheet(sheetName) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}
```

Further explanation on exactly how to in [this other stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391768/google-spreadsheet-hyperlink-to-a-specific-sheet).

However, once you've embedded the sheet, it doesn't work anymore. I suppose this has to do with the fact that this script makes your button/image work like a link (the script just helps you find the appropriate `#gid=`) so it actually just reloads the whole page, which is not possible in the embedded version.

Any pointers towards the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: I now know why this doesn't work. As stated on [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound):

> Only users who have permission to edit a spreadsheet, document, or form can run its bound script. Collaborators who have only view access cannot open the script editor, although if they make a copy of the parent file, they become the owner of the copy and will be able to see and run a copy of the script.

I however can't seem to understand how to make a bound script into a standalone script that works with the embedded file. I've tried publishing the script by "deploying it as a webapp", but that doesn't work.

**Edit 2**:
I now have a very inelegant way to get the script to work on an embedded version of the spreadsheet, but the spreadsheet isn't the way I want it.

Explanation:
Basically I change the iframe code from this:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET-ID/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false&amp;chrome=false" height="500" width="500"></iframe>
```

To this:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET-ID/edit?usp=sharing?widget=true&amp;headers=false" height="500" width="500"></iframe>
```

This forced me however to show the whole Google Sheets page with the menu and everything. The script works however, I can change to another sheet by clicking on an image.

Now onto the funny part: 
I can hide the menu by adding `&rm=minimal` to the link, *but* now the script no longer works.

Comment: Have you tried to implement the suggested solution in the link you have provided? Can you expound more on the issue? Also, state if you have encountered any error.

Comment: @d.datul1990 Yes, I have implemented the solution, and as I have already mentioned it does work within the spreadhseet or if you embed a shared document, but it doesn't work if you embed it with a "publish" link (the link provided by google spreadsheet that will make it uneditable & look nice & neat). I don't know how more specific I can be with the issue, since I've already stated everything I've tried & learned about it. If you have any ideas what more I could do to give you more information about it, please let me know! And no, I haven't encountered any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are better served creating code to display the data as HTML and deploying it as a web app. From that you could have the web app show the appropriate data based on a selection made. You may want to start here: [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) and then look at [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) as a starting point.  You can now embed the web app in any web page via an iFrame.  This will keep it in a display only mode and the viewer does not need to have permissions to the file as you can run the web app as yourself.